# How to properly retrieve POST data through cURL and PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to extract the data from this web page:

https://portal.icuregswe.org/siri/report/corona.vtfstart

I have identified that this data can be retrieved from https://portal.icuregswe.org/siri/api/reports/GenerateHighChart (POST). My attempted solution in PHP using cURL is as follows:

```
$url = 'https://portal.icuregswe.org/siri/api/reports/GenerateHigh';
 
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: portal.icuregswe.org',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: 179',
    'Origin: https://portal.icuregswe.org',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Referer: https://portal.icuregswe.org/siri/report/corona.vtfstart',
    'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1861236498.1591648329; _gid=GA1.2.1182050970.1608386303',
    'Pragma: no-cache',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache'));

$output = curl_exec ($ch);

print $output;

curl_close ($ch);
```

I am expecting to retrieve the raw data but instead I am getting HTTP Error 400. The header is generated by accessing the given url in Firefox. Any help would be appreciated how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no need to lie on the useragent, they don't run a user-agent blacklist; but it does require a bunch of POST parameters, and in fact, you don't need ANY of those headers (well, except the Content-Type header, but curl will add that for you automatically when setting CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to a string, so you don't need to add it yourself, where you might risk introducing typos, while curl won't, so it's better if you don't), this

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://portal.icuregswe.org/siri/api/reports/GenerateHighChart',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
        'highChartUrl' => '/api/reports/GenerateHighChart',
        'tableUrl' => '/api/reports/GenerateExcel',
        'chartWidth' => '900',
        'reportName' => 'corona.vtfstart',
        'startdat' => '2020-01-01',
        'stopdat' => '2020-12-19',
        'sasong' =>
        array(
            0 => '2020',
        ),
    ))
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

outputs:

```
{"ReportName":"Antal nyinskrivna vårdtillfällen med Coronavirus \\n Period ###","ChartTitle":"Antal nyinskrivna vårdtillfällen med Coronavirus ","ChartSubTitle":" Period 2020-01-01 - 2020-12-19","ChartColors":["#53a8c3","#ee5773","#f0d86e","#f6854f","#15ceac","#5773ee","#f597a9","#df7f23","#10a085","#986ef0"],"YaxisTitle":"Antal vtf","YaxisTitleColor":"","HasY2Axis":false,"Y2axisTitle":null,"Y2axisTitleColor":null,"XaxisTitle":"Datum","XaxisColors":["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],"Credits":"Detta är en originalrapport från Svenska Intensivvårdsregistret","SqlString":"<b>-- SQL-sats 1</b><br />SELECT<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Xa.VtfStart)) AS vtfstartdag@0,<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;SUM(CASE WHEN Xa.InfEnkatSiriLabfyndId=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS antalcorona@1,<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;COUNT(DISTINCT Xa.PersonId) AS antalpersoner@2<br />FROM<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;vueSiri AS Xa<br />WHERE<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;(Xa.InfEnkatSiriLabfyndId=3) AND ((Xa.VtfStart>='2020-01-01 00:00:00') AND (Xa.VtfStart<='2020-12-19 23:59:00'))<br />GROUP BY<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Xa.VtfStart))<br />ORDER BY<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;vtfstartdag@0<br /><br />","ChartSeries":[{"Name":"Antal vtf","Stack":null,"Type":"column","Color":"","Data":[{"Value":1.0,"Name":"2020-03-06 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":1.0,"Name":"2020-03-07 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":1.0,"Name":"2020-03-08 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":1.0,"Name":"2020-03-09 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":3.0,"Name":"2020-03-10 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":1.0,"Name":"2020-03-11 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":3.0,"Name":"2020-03-13 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":7.0,"Name":"2020-03-14 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":6.0,"Name":"2020-03-15 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":6.0,"Name":"2020-03-16 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":3.0,"Name":"2020-03-17 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":15.0,"Name":"2020-03-18 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":13.0,"Name":"2020-03-19 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":20.0,"Name":"2020-03-20 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":19.0,"Name":"2020-03-21 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":33.0,"Name":"2020-03-22 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":45.0,"Name":"2020-03-23 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":44.0,"Name":"2020-03-24 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":43.0,"Name":"2020-03-25 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":45.0,"Name":"2020-03-26 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":40.0,"Name":"2020-03-27 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":34.0,"Name":"2020-03-28 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":51.0,"Name":"2020-03-29 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":40.0,"Name":"2020-03-30 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":44.0,"Name":"2020-03-31 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":60.0,"Name":"2020-04-01 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":55.0,"Name":"2020-04-02 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":54.0,"Name":"2020-04-03 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":49.0,"Name":"2020-04-04 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":56.0,"Name":"2020-04-05 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":59.0,"Name":"2020-04-06 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":58.0,"Name":"2020-04-07 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":62.0,"Name":"2020-04-08 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":52.0,"Name":"2020-04-09 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":45.0,"Name":"2020-04-10 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":61.0,"Name":"2020-04-11 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":45.0,"Name":"2020-04-12 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":59.0,"Name":"2020-04-13 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":56.0,"Name":"2020-04-14 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":45.0,"Name":"2020-04-15 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":51.0,"Name":"2020-04-16 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":54.0,"Name":"2020-04-17 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":43.0,"Name":"2020-04-18 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":42.0,"Name":"2020-04-19 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":37.0,"Name":"2020-04-20 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":52.0,"Name":"2020-04-21 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":64.0,"Name":"2020-04-22 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":44.0,"Name":"2020-04-23 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":66.0,"Name":"2020-04-24 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":37.0,"Name":"2020-04-25 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":33.0,"Name":"2020-04-26 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":38.0,"Name":"2020-04-27 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":40.0,"Name":"2020-04-28 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":35.0,"Name":"2020-04-29 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":53.0,"Name":"2020-04-30 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":30.0,"Name":"2020-05-01 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":43.0,"Name":"2020-05-02 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":36.0,"Name":"2020-05-03 00:00:00","Color":null},{"Value":33.0,"Name":"2020-05-04 00:00:00","Color":null},}
```

(...capped, but you get the idea)

Comment: perhaps worth noting for some that by explicitly modifying the supplied data with `http_build_query` you change the encoding of the data to `url-encoded` whereas supplying a raw array will submit the data with `multipart/form-data` encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy and paste to see the result. I am also saving cookies in case we need later.

```
$end_date= date('Y-m-d');//You dont have to use like this, you can write directly the date in the array below.
$start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-91 day"));
$data = array(
    'highChartUrl'=> '/api/reports/GenerateHighChart',
    'tableUrl'=> '/api/reports/GenerateExcel',
    'chartWidth'=> '900',
    'reportName'=> 'corona.vtfstart',
    'startdat'=> $start_date,
    'stopdat'=> $end_date,
    'sasong[0]'=> '2020'
);
$url = 'https://portal.icuregswe.org/siri/api/reports/GenerateHighChart';
$ch = CURL_INIT();
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); //Post request
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) ."/cookie.txt");
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) ."/cookie.txt");
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //ALLOW REDIRECTION
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,90);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,90); 
$result = CURL_EXEC($ch);
echo $result;
```